# Chrome extension to change User Agent only in current tab

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, user-agent

I've used the dev tools to change the user agent, but that's annoying because it means you need to have dev tools open.

I've used extensions to change the user agent, but they all seem to affect all tabs.

Are there any extensions that just affect the current tab?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[User agent Selector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-selector/fnbmdojpgjpmjjmnjdnbobcdhenmmgod?hl=en) will do this functionality,

[image]

From their extension info page:

```
Allows per-tab switching of the User-Agent HTTP header. 
additionally You can also add, edit, export and import your own User-Agents.
```

Comment: Thanks. At first I thought it wasn't working at all, but turns out Google doesn't render the mobile version based on the extensions iPad2 user agent... does support per-tab switching though, which is what I wanted :)

Answer (score 2):

All such chrome extensions available in store use `chrome.webRequest` API to modify request headers like `User-Agent`.

I will suggest to take a look on [Requestly](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/requestly-redirect-url-mo/mdnleldcmiljblolnjhpnblkcekpdkpa) chrome extension where you are allowed to easily setup rules on website URLs or domains so that whenever that website is opened in some browser tab, the User Agent is automatically overridden. The best part here is that you can simultaneously run multiple rules for multiple websites.

See screenshot:
[image]

For more info, please visit blog: https://medium.com/@requestly_ext/switching-user-agent-in-browser-f57fcf42a4b5

To install, visit chrome store page: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/requestly-redirect-url-mo/mdnleldcmiljblolnjhpnblkcekpdkpa

The extension is also available for Firefox. Visit http://www.requestly.in for details.